# Simple Simulations in R: Stochastic Simulation Mean does not match Truncated Normal Expectation

Tags: r, math, simulation, probability, montecarlo

I'm making up a financial forecasting project for school. I run stochastic simulations a hypothetical insurance company's "equity" going into the future by the following:

Take starting reserve, add in interest and revenue, and then subtract out annual loss to get the next year's equity. Repeat that going forward, but using previous year's equity instead of the reserve. If equity ever hits 0 or below, it gets stuck at 0 forever (bankruptcy as an absorbing state).

Losses are distributed by the truncated normal distribution, with a left truncation @ 0. Does anybody know why the expected path is so inaccurate for certain simulations? I'm using the conditional expectation formulas from [this wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)

I tried to make an expected path for the simulation, but it seems I can't get this path to match the mean of my simulations! My strategy thus far is (I believe) akin to E(X) = E(X|x>0)*Pr(x>0). Apologies, as I don't know latex.

Any ideas as to where this goes wrong?

Here's my code:

```
# This is just for looking at the exp_path vs. mean path

library(crch)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(matrixStats)

num_sim = 100000
rev = 100
reserve = 10
exp_loss = 100
st_dv_loss = 20
real_return = 0.03
plan_horzn = 30

# Simulated forecast
sim_data = matrix(data = NA, nrow = plan_horzn, ncol = num_sim)
sim_data[1,1:num_sim] = as.vector(rep(reserve, num_sim))

for (i in 2:plan_horzn){
  equity_vec <- sim_data[i-1,]*(1+real_return) + rev - rtnorm(num_sim, mean = exp_loss, sd = st_dv_loss, left = 0, right = Inf)
  equity_vec[equity_vec < 0] <- 0
  equity_vec[sim_data[i-1,]==0] <- 0
  sim_data[i,] <- equity_vec
}

# My expected forecast path
exp_path = vector(length = plan_horzn)
exp_path[1] = reserve

for (i in 2:plan_horzn){
  cash = exp_path[i-1]*(1+real_return) + rev
  prob = ptnorm(cash, mean = exp_loss, sd = st_dv_loss, left = 0)
  cond_loss = exp_loss + st_dv_loss*(dnorm((0 - exp_loss)/st_dv_loss, mean = 0, sd = 1)-dnorm((cash - exp_loss)/st_dv_loss, mean = 0, sd = 1))/(pnorm((cash - exp_loss)/st_dv_loss, mean = 0, sd = 1) - pnorm((0 - exp_loss)/st_dv_loss, mean = exp_loss, sd = st_dv_loss))
  exp_path[i] = (cash - cond_loss)*prob
}

#Plotting a comparison between the mean and expected path
mean <- rowMeans(sim_data)
sim_summary<- data.frame(mean)
sim_summary$med_pc = rowQuantiles(sim_data, probs = .50)
sim_summary$yr <- seq(1,plan_horzn)
sim_summary$expected <- exp_path
sim_summary_adj <- reshape2::melt(sim_summary, id.var = "yr")

g1 <- ggplot(data = sim_summary_adj, aes(x = yr, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs( x = "Time (Yrs)",
        y = "Equity ($) ",
        title = "Company Equity Over Time",
        color = "Legend") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Mean", "Median", "Exp"), values = c("blue", "purple", "green"))+
  theme_minimal()

plot(g1)
```

Comment: You shouldn't restrict the losses to be greater than zero. That's entirely unrealistic. You should be examining the year-end values for being less than zero. I'm also thinking losses should be a skewed distribution with a center greater than zero but a longer tail on the "left". That the reality that is reflected in stock market results.

Comment: Actually, for an insurance company will never have negative losses. You don't file a claim just to give them money. So I really don't understand your thinking there.... You thought this was a stock price sim, maybe? It isn't, sorry if that wasn't clear.

I do condition on the year end values being zero in my expected path. If loss > cash on hand, then equity hits 0.

Comment: OK on the losses always being positive, but still not ok on them being truncated normal unless the mean and sd are chosen correctly. When you ask about "certain simulation", I think (a) you should use set.seed(...) to make this reproducible and then (b) make reference to which simulation you consider problematic.

Comment: It's just an application of the central limit theorem since the losses are really the sum of a large pool of insured losses, but I like to truncate it at 0 for these stress tests, as I previously mentioned.  Yep, I set a seed on my main script. This code sample is provided with settings that will always expose the issue I'm having on the provided graph.